# Why can't I access 'virtualenv'?

Tags: 16.04, python, virtualenv

[image]

I've just created a new user account called deployer in my 16.04 VPS and I'd like to create a virtualenv inside directory Env. However:

```
deployer@server:~$ cd Env/
deployer@server:~/Env$ virtualenv sample
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
deployer@server:~/Env$ which virtualenv
deployer@server:~/Env$
```

But when I run pip list I see:

```
deployer@server:~$ pip list
click (6.7)
....
uWSGI (2.0.14)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.6)
virtualenvwrapper (4.7.2)
```

Why can't I access 'virtualenv' ?

Edit:

```
deployer@server:~$ find . -iname "virtualenv"
./.local/bin/virtualenv
deployer@server:~$ find /usr/ -iname "virtualenv" | grep bin
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

edit2:

```
deployer@server:~$ find . -iname "virtualenv"
./.local/bin/virtualenv
deployer@server:~$ find /usr/ -iname "virtualenv" | grep bin
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
deployer@server:~$
```

Comment: This implies that virtualenv isn't installed. Have you installed it?

Comment: No, but isn't it already installed? (given the pip list output?)

Comment: Can you report the output of :   find . -iname "virtualenv"  and find /usr/ -iname "virtualenv" | grep bin

Comment: Please see edit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `which virtualenv` and `find /usr/ -iname "virtualenv" | grep bin` should return`/usr/bin/virtualenv`. virtualenv is not installed in the right directory. It should be installed in `/usr/bin/virtualenv` instead of `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` so reinstall it.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-virtualenv
```

For concise information about virtualenv basic usage visit [Virtual Environments — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: please see edit 2:

Comment: I'm confused about this .local directory. Why is this being used?

Comment: Also how does "sudo apt install --reinstall python-virtualenv  " differ from "pip install virtualenv" ?

Comment: pip (provided by *python-pip* in the default Ubuntu repositories) is an alternative Python package installer. It integrates with virtualenv, doesn't do partial installs, and can install from version control repositories. pip can also do either global installs using `sudo pip` or local installs inside virtualenv as a non-root user. Global installs with pip do not always install to the same directory as normal installations using apt in Ubuntu do. The `--reinstall` option was included in the answer to repair pip in case the python-pip package was already installed

Answer (score 0):

As told [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart), you should use

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

to install the command and

```
python3.6 -m venv sample
```

to create a virtual environment named sample.